# How to print the operator as an output?

Tags: python

I have a scenario where I want to print the a symbol.

For example let's assume you have 2 values: `a=10` and `b=20`

Need to check `a` is greater, smaller, or equal to `b`, and then print the relationship as a symbol.

i.e.

`a=10, b=20`  → `<` 
`a=10, b=5`   → `>` 
`a=10, b=10`  → `=`

Comment: No, I'm really sorry. I've missed many opportunities to submit answers because the question gets closed too soon.

Comment: Well, I saw your comment: `Why '=' for 10 and 20?` and realised that the OP wasn't engaging with the contributors like yourself.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode : Its tyo error bro .. writing question on stackoverflow is little bit time consuming becasue good question will make user contribute or make my question down vote and dont let me post question again

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode: Now's your chance to post your answer!

Comment: @quamrana Thanks. Had to type it again, as SO apparently forgets drafts during closures, but not too bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple set of comparisons and a [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings):

```
a=10
b=20 

print(f'{a} {"<" if a<b else ">" if a>b else "="} {b}')
```

example outputs:

```
20 = 20
10 < 20
20 > 10
```

Answer (score 1):

mozway's is clear and efficient, but I also like short:

```
'=<>'[(a<b)-(a>b)]
```

That takes advantage of bools acting as integers 0 and 1 and of negative indexes.

A variation using codeholic24's observation about ASCII:

```
chr(61-(a<b)+(a>b))
```

Demo of both ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/Py2/SCFRRyFJITNPQcNQR8FIU0dBwwhBG2pacSkAQUFRZl6JBlCluq2NnXq0RqJNkqauRqJdkmYsULcmqprkjCINM0NdsCJtsCJNNEWa//8DAA)):

```
for a, b in (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1):
    print(a, '=<>'[(a<b)-(a>b)], b)
    print(a, chr(61-(a<b)+(a>b)), b)
    print()
```

Output:

```
1 < 2
1 < 2

2 = 2
2 = 2

2 > 1
2 > 1
```

Python 2: If you ever find yourself wanting this for codegolfing, might want to use Python 2 which has `'=<>'[cmp(b-a,0)]`.

Comment: `chr(61-(a<b)+(a>b))` can you elaborate what internally happening